# Is it possible to convert a angular PWA to a flutter application or maybe combine the both?

Tags: angular, flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web, angular-dart

I am trying to convert an Angular PWA to a Flutter application as the mobile version of the Angular app is not exactly performing all the necessary steps. I would be fine with combining the both languages to if that is possible.

I did research about it and what i found was that you can combine the databases but i would love to find any alternatives if available.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not sure if you're going to the stores with this app, but they will reject anything that looks like a repackaged PWA.